# List db_owner privileges on each database for a user

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a user John.Smith and I want to know what database he have `db_owner` too and  well as what database he doesn't have `db_owner`. Is there a script I can run? We have a lot of database and when I look at the usermap I feel like I might be over looking something.

Comment: You have tagged both sql server and mysql.  The answer is different for each.

Comment: Hi Dan - i work in sql sever 2008 R2 - was looking for an sql that would work in 2008 R2. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ##DBOwners
(
    DBName SYSNAME,
    Username SYSNAME,
    Rolename NVARCHAR(50),
    IsOwner BIT
);

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
    '
        USE [?];
        INSERT INTO ##DBOwners
            SELECT
                DB_NAME(),
                dp.name,
                dp2.name,
                CASE 
                    WHEN dp2.name = ''db_owner'' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS ''db_owner''
            FROM
                sys.database_principals AS dp
            LEFT JOIN
                sys.database_role_members AS rm
                    ON
                        rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
            LEFT JOIN
                sys.database_principals AS dp2
                    ON
                        rm.role_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
            WHERE
                dp.type <> ''R''
    '

SELECT * FROM ##DBOwners WHERE Username = 'John.Smith'
DROP TABLE ##DBOwners;
```

It gathers information about all databases by using the stored procedure sp_MSforeachdb and saving the results in a global temp table.

Comment: Hi thank you for the code! will this also show what db John.Smith does not belong as a db_owner too? when i ran the code i can see that db's that John.Smith belongs to as db_owner but it doesnt tell me what db he doesnt belong too